# Getting Canadian visa decisions if agent is nonresponsive

Tags: visas, indian-citizens, canada, visa-refusals, standard-visitor-visas

I am from India - Hyderabad. I have applied for Canada Visitor Visa through Agent. But unfortunately the Agents office if closed and I am not able to check my Visa decision. The Agent have not even shared the GC-Key with us.  Is there a way that I can get my Decision if its already done? Kindly guide

Comment: Perhaps you can try to contact the [Canadian High Commission](https://travel.gc.ca/assistance/embassies-consulates/india) in New Delhi.

Comment: Have you paid the ‘agent’  a fee upfront? It is not normally essential to use one https://www.canada.ca/en/immigration-refugees-citizenship/services/visit-canada/about-visitor-visa.html

Comment: Do you even know whether the agent really submitted your application?  Is the office a real physical building which you have seen?

Comment: are sure the agent was real and not just a scammer ?

Answer (score 8):

I am assuming that your agent has not given you any communications from IRCC (Immigration Refugees and Citizenship Canada). If they have, then there should be two numbers listed as part of this - your UCI (Unique Client Identifier) and your Application Number (or File Number). If you have either of those then you can contact IRCC and identify yourself and get details of your application progress. (Assuming they are genuine of course). If you have previously made a visa application to Canada then your UCI will not have changed - contact them using it and get details of any application in progress.

If your "Agent" is an unofficial agent who has offered to do your application for a fee, and they have not given you any IRCC correspondence or the above numbers, and especially if they said you would get a better outcome by using them, I'm afraid it's likely that you have been scammed. Most likely they have simply pocketed the fees you paid and done nothing. (It could be worse - sometimes they will try to come back and get more money saying that there are "additional fees" or they "need a deposit of thousands of dollars to prove you have sufficient funds"). This unfortunately is very common with applications for Canadian visas - so common that the Canadian government explicitly warns against such scams.

It is illegal for people to charge you for representing you to immigration unless they are [a lawyer, a notary or an approved member of the College of Immigration Consultants](https://www.cic.gc.ca/english/helpcentre/answer.asp?qnum=423&top=16). If your agent was one of the above, you should be able to contact them, and if they don't respond you can report them to their professional organization.  If they were not then there is virtually nothing that Canadian authorities can do about this - you could try reporting them to your local law enforcement.

Your best bet is to begin a new application by yourself. The application for a visitor visa is pretty straightforward and an agent will give you virtually no benefit even when they are legit.

Comment: The agent taking the money without submitting an application may be the best outcome -- certainly better than the agent submitting a deceptive application, which can lead to long-term problems.

Comment: I just checked the costs.  The first visa agent I found online was charging a premium of roughly 67% over the bare visa fee (though I didn't look long enough to see what additional services this supposedly includes).  A Canadian tourist visa costs CAD 100, which is roughly INR 6150 at today's exchange rate.